# Show that $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $f_k \to f$ a.e. on $B=B(0,1)$ , and $\forall \epsilon >0$ there is $T>0$ such that $\int_{ \{ f_k >T \} } f_k(x) dx < \epsilon$. Show that $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(B)$.

Is my proof correct?

**Proof**

Let $\epsilon >0$, from the asumption, there $T>0$ such that

$$\int_{ \{|f_k -f| > T\}  } |f_k -f| dx \leq \int_{f_k > T} |f_k| dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Let $E = \{|f_k -f| \leq T \}$. By Egoroff's theorem , there is $A \subset E$ such that $|A| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4T}$ and $f_k \to f$ uniformly on $E \setminus A$. Then we have

$$\int_E |f_k -f| dx \leq \int_{E \setminus A} |f_k-f|dx + \int_A |f_k -f| dx .$$

From the uniform convergence, there is $N >0$ such that $|f_k - f| < \frac{\epsilon}{4 |E \setminus A|}$ for $k > N$. Then

\begin{align}
\int_E |f_k -f| dx &\leq \int_{E \setminus A} |f_k -f |dx + \int_A |f_k -f| dx\\
& < \frac{\epsilon}{4} + T \int_A dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}

Now, we have

$$\int_B |f_k - f| dx\leq \int_{|f_k -f| < T} |f_k - f|dx + \int_{|f_k - f| \geq T} |f_k - f|dx< \epsilon,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall k >N.$$

Comment: You don't need Egorov's Theorem. The condition you mentioned is known as uniform integrability and in finite measure spaces, convergence in measure coupled with uniform integrability implies $L^{1}$ convergence and conversely. Although, one uses the fact that if $f_{n}\to f$ a.e. then $f_{n}\to f$ in measure, i.e. $\mu\{|f_{n}-f|>a\}\to 0$ for all $a>0$ whose proof is a bit similar to Egorov's theorem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relation_to_convergence_of_random_variables) or [here](https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Uniform.html)